# Outputting dynamic php content from a drupal 7 module

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've written a module in Drupal 7 to output an overview page for a project management application. However Im not sure how to reference php variables in the block out put. This block content is to be displayed through the main content area.

I initially thought I might be able to do something like this (i.e. fullpath represent a path to an image which will change dynamically based on a returned db query).

```
$block['content'] = ("<div><p>Overview stuff <?php echo $fullPath?></p></div>");
```

However the php element doesn't come through and I don't think that's the proper way to do it anyway. I've not yet had any experience with .tpl.php files but that might be the way to go. I've checked on google for a solution and currently going through the docs but not found something yet.

Can anyone give me a idea of how I should go about this?

Many thanks

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
 $block['content'] = array(
     '#markup' => t('Overview stuff') . ' ' . $fullPath,
     '#prefix' => '<div><p>',
     '#suffix' => '</p></div>',
 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I have three sets of these each with nine images to display. each image is in a div which is then wrapped in another couple of divs for labels/classes etc. Am I better trying to go the tpl.php route instead of many render arrays?......thanks alot for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it would probably be easier creating a template for that. Do all the logic in the preprocess function, making the variables available to the template.

Comment: Yep template is the way forward for this, thanks for your help.